# Case list view not working as expected in community

Tags: community, case, customer-community, list-view, community-builder

I have created a list view on the case which is being used in a community. When a community user creates a record, it is not displayed in the list view. The image below shows the filter criteria,
[image]

Comment: Check that when Community user creates Case record, who is the owner of that case? My case in list view means current user is the case owner

Comment: Owner is a community user only.

Comment: If community user is owner then how user can wirk on the case?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you